# How to join two streaming datasets when one dataset involves aggregation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am getting below error in below code snippet -

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations
>   on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;

Below is my input schema

```
val schema = new StructType()
.add("product",StringType)
.add("org",StringType)
.add("quantity", IntegerType)
.add("booked_at",TimestampType)
```

Creating streaming source dataset

```
val payload_df = spark
.readStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
.option("subscribe", "test1")
.option("startingOffsets", "latest")
.load()
.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as payload")
.select(from_json(col("payload"), schema).as("data"))
.select("data.*")
```

Creating another streaming dataframe where aggregation is done and then joining it with original source dataframe to filter out records

```
payload_df.createOrReplaceTempView("orders")
    val stage_df = spark.sql("select org, product, max(booked_at) as booked_at from orders group by 1,2")
  stage_df.createOrReplaceTempView("stage")

  val total_qty = spark.sql(
    "select o.* from orders o join stage s on o.org = s.org and o.product = s.product and o.booked_at > s.booked_at ")
```

Finally, I was trying to display results on console with Append output mode. I am not able to figure out where I need to add watermark or how to resolve this. My objective is to filter out only those events in every trigger which have higher timestamp then the maximum timestamp received in any of the earlier triggers

```
total_qty
    .writeStream
    .format("console")
    .outputMode("append")
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

With spark structured streaming you can make aggregation directly on stream only with watermark. If you have a column with the timestamp of the event you can do it like this:

```
val payload_df = spark
.readStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
.option("subscribe", "test1")
.option("startingOffsets", "latest")
.load()
.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as payload")
.select(from_json(col("payload"), schema).as("data"))
.select("data.*")
.withWatermark("event_time", "1 minutes")
```

On queries with aggregation you have 3 types of outputs:

- **Append mode** uses watermark to drop old aggregation state. But the output of a windowed aggregation is delayed the late threshold
  specified in `withWatermark()` as by the modes semantics, rows can be
  added to the Result Table only once after they are finalized (i.e.
  after watermark is crossed). See the Late Data section for more
  details.
- **Update mode** uses watermark to drop old aggregation state.
- **Complete mode** does not drop old aggregation state since by definition this mode preserves all data in the Result Table.

Edit later:
You have to add window on your groupBy method.
val aggFg = payload_df.groupBy(**window($"event_time", "1 minute")**, $"org", $"product")
.agg(max(booked_at).as("booked_at"))

Comment: I tried adding watermark while creating payload_df as you suggested (booked_at is my timestamp field) but it still gives the same error. Please note that after creating this streaming dataframe, I am doing other operations on it (agg and then join)

Comment: I edited my answer. I have an application that does almost that you are doing and it works like that.